# preg_replace (or other) to remove duplicate tags

Tags: php, html, regex

I'm merging two HTML files together, and as such, they have duplicate `<head> </head>`, `<html> </html>` and `<body> </body>` tags. Is there a way to get preg_replace remove **only** the *second* batch of duplicate tags, so the content of the second document blend together without any problems?

If not with preg_replace, is there another way of doing this?

Conceptual Information:

In this instance, there are two files. There will be more eventually.

Each file starts off like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type='text/css'>
(Template Data)
</style>
</head>
<body>
```

My script is taking those files (which live in some directory), and creating a NEW file that combines both outputs. However, the result of this is something along the lines of:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type='text/css'>
(Template Data)
</style>
</head>
<body>
blah blah blah
<html>
<head>
<style type='text/css'>
(Template Data)
</style>
</head>
<body>
blah blah blah 2
```

This creates duplicate tags.  The desired output would be:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type='text/css'>
(Template Data)
</style>
</head>
<body>
Blah blah blah
Blah blah blah 2
```

Essentially cutting out the head data for all of the HTML files outside of the first one processed through a while loop

Thanks so much!

Comment: Can you tell me why you have come to the conclusion that regular expressions are your solution?

Comment: I knew it could remove an entire tag and everything in it, was hoping maybe there was a parameter to search only for the second duplicate.

Comment: @zackt147: So, no solid reason. DOM manipulation is better suited to this line of work. When you read in the second document, extract the _contents_ of its `body` node and insert it into the DOM of the original document.

Comment: No solid reason, hence why it's being asked. Cheers! :)

Comment: @zackt147: Then I'd suggest editing your question to be more general, and to not include this assumed solution. Let the answers decide the solution! (Also, please use "@name:" syntax on SO to provoke reply notifications.)

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal It was edited 14 minutes ago to do just that. And, as per your bio, "sometimes you're just curious about something, even if it's not necessarily the best way to achieve a goal. "

Comment: @zackt147: I still see specific mentions of regex in it (the title and tags, in particular).

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal Yeah, I tried to specify "or other" in both the title and text because there could be a preg_replace solution (as posted by Radu)

Comment: @zackt147 Why do you actually want to do this? Unless the sites you're merging share the same stylesheets / scripts I can only see this ending badly...
If you have to show another site within yours have you considered IFrames or any other approaches?

Comment: @user519575 The stylesheets for all files are exactly the same as they are all dynamically generated the same way.

Comment: Can you pastebin an example of the output you are trying to regex, because your statement of "Is there a way to get preg_replace remove only the second batch of duplicate tags, so the content of the second document blend together without any problems?" can be interpreted several different ways.

Comment: @Robin Maybe this will help? http://pastebin.com/7hxKUYSH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just apply the tag removal on the second HTML *before* you merge it, then merge the first HTML with the stripped second HTML.

Here's a pseudocode example if you have more HTMLs to merge:

```
$strip_tags = false;
foreach ($htmls_to_merge as $html) {
    if ($strip_tags) { // this will be false in the first iteration, then true 
        $html = what you do to strip the tags;
    }
    merge;
    $strip_tags = true;
}
```

Comment: It's merging the files through a loop though, so I have no idea how to indicate which one is first.

Comment: You can set something like `$strip_tags = false` before the loop, then, inside the loop, `if ($strip_tags) { strip the tags }`, then, just before the end of the loop, `$strip_tags = true`.

Comment: Oooh. That's clever. And is there a way to do `<head><body>` and `<html>` all in one push? right now I have `$somecontent = preg_replace("#(.*)<head>(.*?)</head>(.*)#is", '$2', $somecontent);` just for the head tags.

Comment: @zackt147, I'm not exactly sure what you want to achieve with your regex.

Comment: I upvoted. Not sure who downvoted.  Just curious, is there a way to do it with while instead of foreach? I'm pulling the file names from a sql statement, which is being looped through a while like: (`$strip_tags=false;
$sql="select * from table where something=something";
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$filename = $row['filename'];
if($strip_tags) {
$somecontent .= file_get_contents($filename);
$somecontent2 = preg_replace('#<(head|body|html)>.*?</\1>#is', '$2', $somecontent2);

$strip_tags=true;

}`)
That attempted method didn't work

Comment: @Radu Oh, and then it uses fopen / fwrite to write the contents from $somecontent.

Comment: @zackt147, I removed the earlier regex. As I was saying, I'm not exactly sure what you want to achieve with it. That regex that I posted would likely remove everything in the file, since everything will probably be between `<html>` and `</html>` tags.

Comment: @Radu Hmm, I'll try to explain it better. I just realized it makes no sense. I want the first file that is merged to retain the `<html><head><body>` tags. I want every file after that to be stripped of those tags, so that it blends right in to the first document's <body> tag without starting anew. Does that make sense?

Comment: @zackt147, ah, so you get the first file, then with a regex replace the contents of the body tag with the contents of the other files concatenated, but with their `<html>`, `</html>`, `<body>` and `</body>` tags removed, and also the `<head>` tag plus everything after it until `</head>` removed?

Comment: @Radu That sounds about right. My problem is finding the appropriate regex for this function.

Comment: @zackt147, you can use something like `preg_replace(array('#<(?:/?(?:html|body))>#i', '#<head>.*?</head>#is'), '', $html_to_strip)`.

Comment: @zack147, you should however make sure that the HTMLs you need to parse contain exactly this structure, since parsing HTMLs with regexps is usually a [bad idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). If however you're sure that the tags don't contain newlines, don't have attributes, get closed properly, are not present in other parts of the text, etc (as the regexp requires), then you'll be fine (and only then). Do consider using [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php).

Comment: @Radu That seems to do the right stuff to the actual html! But it deletes the head content for the first one as well. I put `$strip_html = false;` before the while loop. Then I did `if($strip_html = false) { (merge) }` and set `strip_html = true;` at the end of it. Doesn't seem to want to keep the first one...

Comment: Well, the thing with the `$strip_html` variable wouldn't work like this (I misunderstood what you wanted to do). Create 2 variables: one to hold the parent HTML (the one which will contain the others) and another to contain the others. If `$strip_html` is false, store the HTML you find in the parent. Otherwise, merge the current HTML with the previous children. After the loop, add the children to the parent's body.

Comment: @Radu Hmm. I'm trying to store the `<head>` content in the `$somecontent` variable before the loop. Then I do `if($strip_html == false) { $somecontent .= file_get_contents($filename); } else { $somecontent .= file_get_contents($filename); $somecontent = preg_replace(array('#<(?:/?(?:html|body))>#i', '#<head>.*?</head>#is'), '', $somecontent2);`

Then for writing:
`if (!$handle = fopen($filename, 'w+')) {
        
              exit;
          } 
         
          if (fwrite($handle, $somecontent) === false) {
              
              exit;
          }`

Comment: The problem with that is, it appends even the $somecontent template I created earlier...there's no way to distinguish the variables because it all has to be put into the fopen/fwrite script as $somecontent. >.<

Comment: (For conceptual reference: http://pastebin.com/7hxKUYSH)

Thanks for the help thus far, btw.

Comment: @Radu Figured it out! You're probably sick of me, but that all definitely helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [SoftSnow Merger](http://softsnow.griffin3.com/merger/merger.shtml#intro). Not a very hacker-y way of doing things but as long as it works...

Comment: This has to be done through PHP to integrate with my website when toggled by a user. :(